# JBoss upgrade from 4.3 to 5.1, java.lang.LinkageError

Tags: jboss5.x, jboss-4.2.x

Hi I am working on JBoss upgrade  from 4.3 to 5.1. Application(Built with Maven) deployed without any error but throwing below error after login. Can you please advise what am I missing?

```
ERROR [Test Logger] java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation:
when resolving method "org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.client.ServiceFactoryImpl.createService(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/net/URL;)Ljavax/xml/rpc/Service;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, com/test/test1/test2/test3/service/TestServiceImpl, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) for resolved class, org/jboss/ws/core/jaxrpc/client/ServiceFactoryImpl, have different Class objects for the type javax/xml/namespace/QName used in the signature
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method
        at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:294)    
  at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:187)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
        at com.test.test1.test2.action.TestRequestProcessor.process(TestRequestProcessor.java:86)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
```